# I want to compute specific field in my db depends on ID_number

Tags: php, codeigniter

This is my model

```
public function total_late()
    {

        $query = "SELECT sum(late_deduction) as late_deduction FROM tbl_dtr";
        $result = $this->db->query($query);
        return $result->row()->late_deduction;
    }
```

This the image of the database:

[image: db]

This is the image of my table:

[image: table]

This is my another model for my table in view

```
function get_faculty_payroll($limit, $start, $string = "", $orderField, $orderDirection)
    {  
       $this->db->group_start()
                        ->where('tbl_employee' . '.department_id', 3)
                ->group_end()
                ->group_start()
                        ->or_like('first_name', $string)
                        ->or_like('last_name', $string)
                ->group_end()
                ->join('tbl_employee_department', 'tbl_employee.department_id = tbl_employee_department.department_id')
                ->join('tbl_rates', 'tbl_employee.ID_number = tbl_rates.ID_number')
                ->limit($limit, $start)
                ->order_by($orderField, $orderDirection);
       $query = $this->db->get('tbl_employee');
       return $query->result();
    }
```

This is my table:

[image]

Comment: where condition?

Comment: use `where` condition

Comment: Are you trying to output a new field name and calculate the value depending on the number of the id?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your Controller

```
public function total_late()
{
    $retRes=$this->modelname->total_late($ID_number);
}
```

Your model

```
public function total_late($ID_number)
{

    $query = "SELECT sum(late_deduction) as late_deduction
              FROM tbl_dtr WHERE ID_number = '$ID_number'";
    $result = $this->db->query($query);
    return $result->row()->late_deduction;
}
```

However, this code is better, as it handles parameters safely, and avoids SQL injection vulnerabilities:

```
$stmt = $this->db->prepare("
    SELECT sum(late_deduction) as late_deduction
    FROM tbl_dtr WHERE ID_number = ?
");

$stmt->execute(array($ID_number));
```

Comment: at first it says undefined variable ID_number ,, then i tried declaring ID_number in my controller ,, then it displays nothing..

Comment: actually sir it did work when i chose the specific ID_number but im trying to show it in one table with different ID_numbers

Answer (score 0):

Try This,

```
public function total_late()
{
  $query = "SELECT sum(late_deduction) as late_deduction FROM tbl_dtr where ID_number = 'C-08011'";
  $result = $this->db->query($query);
  return $result->row()->late_deduction;
}
```

Comment: it did compute the row with the of C-08011 but how about the other one??